# Vb.net: How to add WPF richtextbox to winforms

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a rich-text-files word procsessor, and I want to add the more advanced richtextbox of WPF to my app in winforms.

Is there a way to add WPF richtextbox to winforms?

Comment: What's wrong with the RichTextBox that comes with WinForms? In what way is the WPF RTB "more advanced"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Answer: yes

Long Answers:

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742215.aspx): Walkthrough Hosting a WPF Composite Control in Windows Forms

[CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22849/Integrating-WPF-with-Windows-Forms): Integrating WPF with Windows Forms